# Using Xamarin.Android, how do I reset the selected items in an AlertDialog

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an AlertDialog displaying on a button press which allows the user to select from multiple options. When the AlertDialog is subsequently relaunched, the selection is remembered.

I am using the method SetMultiChoiceItems and passing in an array of bools representing the selection I want but this seems to be ignored (notice I am resetting the selected array on dismissal of the dialog).

```
private AlertDialog OpenSelectMultiplePlayers(List<SelectionViewModel> selections, SelectReason reason)
{
    string[] items = (from p in selections
                      select p.PlayerName).ToArray();
    bool[] selected = new bool[selections.Count];

    var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.SetTitle(Resource.String.select_players);
    builder.SetMultiChoiceItems(items, selected, (s, e) => {
        selected[e.Which] = e.IsChecked;
    });

    builder.SetPositiveButton(Resource.String.alert_dialog_ok, (s, e) =>
    {
        // TODO: Do something with the selection
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++) { selected[i] = false; }
    });

    builder.SetNegativeButton(Resource.String.alert_dialog_cancel, (s, e) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++) { selected[i] = false; }
    });

    return builder.Create();
}
```

Obviously using Xamarin, some of the code will look odd to android developers but am I missing something in my translation?

**EDIT:**
New information: It appears that the subsequent ShowDialog calls do not result in any extra OnCreateDialog executions. OnCreateDialog is the method which executes OpenSelectMultiplePlayers. This means I never even get the chance to re-build the AlertDialog, Andoird/Xamarin is caching this internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OnCreateDialog* is called the first time the dialog needs to be constructed and as you have observed, it is cached.

You need to handle the refresh of elements in *OnPrepareDialog*.

Another option is to explicitly remove the dialog so that it is recreated each time using *RemoveDialog* when you're done with it.